# Loopback error - value is not an object

Tags: express, loopbackjs, loopback

I am using loopback in backend. I am getting this error

```
    Unhandled error for request POST /api/meetups/auth: Error: Value is not an object.
        at errorNotAnObject (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/types/object.js:80:13)
        at Object.validate (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/types/object.js:51:14)
        at Object.fromTypedValue (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/types/object.js:14:22)
        at Object.fromSloppyValue (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/types/object.js:41:17)
        at HttpContext.buildArgs (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/http-context.js:193:22)
        at new HttpContext (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/http-context.js:59:20)
        at restStaticMethodHandler (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/rest-adapter.js:457:15)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at next (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at /Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
        at Function.process_params (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
        at next (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
        at Function.handle 
(/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
        at router (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

I have already searched stackoverflow, but I didnt find answer. Basically, i was trying to use body-parser . I went through one of the stackoverflow thread and implemented its solution. I was able to use body-parser successfully. So, that error has been solved. But, now this error is giving me tough time.

server.js file

```
'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

//code for body parsing
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
//app.use(multer()); // for parsing multipart/form-data

//code for body parsing ends

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});
```

In middleware.json, I have updated parse property as well

```
"parse": {"body-parser#json": {},
    "body-parser#urlencoded": {"params": { "extended": true }}},
```

For some reason, that error has gone. Not sure, may be it will come again. But now, this is the error, I am seeing

```
Unhandled error for request POST /api/meetups/auth: TypeError: cb is not a function
    at Function.Meetups.auth (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/common/models/meetups.js:117:3)
    at SharedMethod.invoke (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/shared-method.js:270:25)
    at HttpContext.invoke (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/http-context.js:297:12)
    at phaseInvoke (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:677:9)
    at runHandler (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/lib/phase.js:135:5)
    at iterate (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)
    at Object.async.eachSeries (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:162:9)
    at runHandlers (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/lib/phase.js:144:13)
    at iterate (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)
    at /Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25
    at /Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:154:25
    at execStack (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:522:7)
    at RemoteObjects.execHooks (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:526:10)
    at phaseBeforeInvoke (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:673:10)
    at runHandler (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/lib/phase.js:135:5)
    at iterate (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)
```

Comment: Difficult to know what your question is. That final stack trace shows a problem on line 117 of `meetups.js`, which you haven't included. Presumably it's trying to call a function called `cb` but, as the error says, `cb` is not a function.

Comment: Encountered "Value is not an object" when my input's type was not the one as expected.

type: 'object' was expected, but an array was passed

Answer (score 0):

check if your filters or your URL has black spaces i.e. %20, or anything wrong with the filter or url.

Answer (score 0):

Loopback 3 makes a difference between `array` and `object`. You have to check your data type. See https://github.com/strongloop/strong-remoting/issues/360 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error but in my case it was due to a model property data length.The property was  type object and a small dataLength which caused faulty record in my sql Model table.I have to Manually delete those faulty records and increase the dataLength of that property too.
Restart the app